# How to get items from SP list using query and @pnp/sp and Filtering

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp, react, pnpjs

I have a `getItems` function that accepts a filter, but I need to know how to pass in two different filters so that I can retrieve items filtered by both Age and First Name.

Here is the definition of the function:

```
public getItems(list: string, id: string, filters?: string[]): Promise<any[]> {

    let filterStr: string = 'startswith(ContentTypeId,\''+ id +'\')';
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let query:any = pnp.sp.web.lists.getById(list).items;
        if(filters)
            filters.map((rowFilter: string) => { filterStr += ' and '+ rowFilter; });
            console.log(filters)
                query.filter(filterStr).get().then(Items => {

                resolve(Items);
            }).catch(e => {
                reject(e);
            });
    });
}`
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Are you getting an error or just unexpected results?  I don't see anything inherently wrong with the code you have posted, perhaps the problem is in the parameter values you are passing for `list`, `id`, or `filters`?  If you can include examples of your parameters in your question we can see where the problem may be.

Comment: I wanted to pass two filters in the method.the method can filter only one column and I need to filter by two column first name and age.                                        
  How i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the definition of the `getItems` function at all.  As it is written, you actually have two different options.  The way that method is concatenating filter strings together, you can just specify to criteria in a single parameter, for example:

```
this.getItems(mylistguid, myctid, "firstnamecol eq 'Alice' and agecol eq 27");
```

But that method is already set up to accept an array of filter strings, and concatenate them together with `and`'s, so you could also call the method with a declared array (e.g. `[filterString1, filterString2]`) like this:

```
this.getItems(mylistguid, myctid, ["firstnamecol eq 'Alice'", "agecol eq 27"]);
```